# Execute app and move log created in a folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run an app and move log created in a folder. Here are my codes. Will this works?

```
Function Execute($command)

{   # execute:
Invoke-Expression $command; }
$extract_path = "E:\Utilities\PeakLicense";
## The name of your executable app
$app = 'E:\Magicxpi49\Runtime\JRE8x64\JRE\bin\java.exe';
## List of arguments:
# -jar Mg-License-Monitor.1.0.jar 1000 ESB-Prod-App01 1000
args = '-jar',
        'Mg-License-Monitor.1.0.jar',
        '1000',
        'ESB-Prod-App01',
        '1000';

## Execute the app and store in extract path
Execute "$app $args" x --o+ -c- "$extract_path";
```

Comment: *"Will this works?"* Execute it and tell us

Comment: What Cid said. You can execute it yourself to see if it works. If something doesn't work as intended, you can ask SO for help. :-)

Comment: I am getting error below

Comment: args :  The term 'args' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\esbadmin\Desktop\RunApp_CreateLog.ps1:11 char:1
+ args = '-jar',
+ ~~~
etc